# Is flow of 4-momentum (across a 1-form) parallel to 4-momentum itself?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

energy momentum tensor represent flow of 4-momentum field (it absorb one 1-form and give a 4-vector as flow of 4-momentum across it). when I think of it I intuitively imagine simple matter and so flow of 4-momentum is parallel to 4-momentum itself by relation $p=mv$. but i think this can't be always the case, first of all because it decrease degree of freedom of $T$ badly. can you give some examples of non-simple matter or other fields in which we don't have this parallel situation?

another may be false intuition is flow of 4-momentum (is as case of simple matter) the result of flow of something (like point particle) and we must keep track of it. in complex matter and field what flows and carry 4-momentum? (that I hope not to be necessarily parallel to each others.)

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that momentum can also flow as a result of forces. For example, take a perfect fluid at rest. Its energy momentum tensor is (in $(- + + +)$ signature)

$$T^{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
\rho & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & p & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & p & 0 \\
                   0 & 0 & 0 & p 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If we take as the normal a pure spatial vector, say $n^\mu = (0, 1, 0, 0)$, then the flow of momentum is $(0, p, 0, 0)$. This is because the piece of fluid is exerting a force on the one next to it, and therefore exchanging momentum, even if nothing is moving.

Comment: thanks. can we look at this situation (no moving -that is zero momentum- but flow of momentum) as "exact analogy" with situation in flux of charges in wire where there is no charge density but charge current? (exact analogy except of course that charge is scalar but momentum is 4-vector)  @Javier

Comment: Definitely not an exact analogy, because in practice charge is always carried by particles, while momentum can be transferred through interactions. Still, you can think of it as a rough analogy, if you want.

Comment: thanks. to understanding flow of momentum i'm thinking pressure as collision of point particle and then simplify it by thinking of Newton cradle. so Newton cradle permits flow of momentum without moving particles. but question is I think in perfect fluid flow of momentum (by Newton cradle mechanism) in every direction is the same and they cancel each other to zero! please say where i'm wrong? @Javier

Comment: When we take a surface with normal $n^\mu$ and calculate $T^{\mu\nu}n_\nu$, we're calculating the momentum transferred from one side to the other of the surface, in the direction of $\vec{n}$. In our example this is proportional to $\vec{n}$, that is, both sides exert force on each other, and the net effect is indeed zero like you say. The energy momentum tensor is not zero because it keeps track of these mutual forces.

Comment: thanks. but you mean $T$ only considers flow of 4-momentum in direction of $\vec n$ and simply ignores flow in $-\vec n$ direction? (so this two flows don't cancel each others when $T$ considers them). but this is in contradiction with linearity of $T$. don't it? (for example if flow be only in one direction then $T$ gives zero for $-\vec n$) or I'm wrong elsewhere? thanks. @Javier

Comment: That's a good question, and I'm not totally sure how to answer it. Linearity doesn't fail, though; if the flow is in one direction and you take the normal opposite to that, the flux will be negative like it should.

Comment: I think I found answer. "if a components of flow of momentum  be in negative direction of an axis then this flow decrees that component of the momentum of the system". so when we see two opposite (exactly negative of each other) flow of momentum between two sides of n imaginary plane, momentum between them  do not exchange but give from some side to other. exchange have zero effect but we have borrowing!  @Javier